# Comparing working hours of an entity per day against the date (day of the week and hours) from the device

Tags: ios, json, swift, date

I would like to compare the working hours per day of an entity, fetched from `JSON`, against the day and hour information from the device. Related to that, I have two questions:

**1)** What is the best/right way of saving information of working hours per day for a particular entity in a `JSON`? I think, its structure should be something like this:

```
  "working_hours": {
           "<DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_1>":"<WORKING_HOURS>",
           "<DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_2>":"<WORKING_HOURS>",
           "<DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_3>":"<WORKING_HOURS>",
           "<DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_4>":"<WORKING_HOURS>",
           "<DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_5>":"<WORKING_HOURS>",
           "<DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_6>":"<WORKING_HOURS>",
           "<DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_7>":"<WORKING_HOURS>"
        }
```

Here, I use days of the week as keys in a `dictionary`. However, I'm not sure what is the best/right way to enter `"<DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_N>"` and `"<WORKING_HOURS>"` inside a `JSON`.

**2)**  After fetching this information, how to compare it against the time information from the device. Basically, I need to check the day of the week and then checking whether the current from the device is within the interval of a particular `<WORKING_HOURS>`.

For those who ask me whether I'm asking about comparing two numbers: I don't ask about that. I need to know the right format to save working hours in `JSON` also taking into account the day changes. 
Currently, the problem is, when I save a time like `21:00` and transform it to a `Date`:

```
   let workingHoursEnd = "21:00"

   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "H:mm"
   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
   let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: workingHoursEnd)
```

I get `Jan 1, 2000 at 9:00 PM`. The time format is ok, I can change it later, however, what I need is to get the current date (especially, day of the week) because I need to take into account the current day, too.

If you can answer to both questions (or even to one of them), I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you are not asking us how to simply compare two numbers at a time right? That’s like elementary math. Are you seriously asking us to provide code to do this task for you?  “Current from the device...”. In amps or milliamperes?

Comment: @zipzit, of course no. I'm asking the best/right format to save the working hours information in a `JSON` (should I use, for example, (08:00 - 24:00) format (for 24-hours) or there is a better way?). And also, I would like to know the best way to compare this to the time information on the device. To do that I need to get that information without year, month and also I should be able to convert 24-hour format to 12 - hour (the working hours from JSON) and vice-versa. I'm not asking you about the ways of comparing two numbers